# PHP confused by for() statement

Tags: php, for-loop

When i write code i have to use loops e.g.

```
$six = 6;
for ($i = $six; $i > 1; $i--) {
   echo $i."<br>";
}
```

outputs

```
6
5
4
3
2
```

i need it to output 1 as well i know i can do `for ($i = 6; $i >= 1; $i--)`

or 
`for ($i = $six+1; $i > 1; $i--)` in evaluation but its confusing so muchg!
in fact i always confused when using `for` statement.

**EDIT:** its confusing because i dont like to think backwards.. id like to run loop not while condition `$six > 1` is true, but rather before condition like `$six = 1` is meet.

the opposite way i guess

```
loop_before ($six==1) {
   echo $six.<br />;
   $six--;
}
```

well even this one wont output 654321... guess i just need to go back to school.
got to do

```
loop_before ($six<1) {
   echo $six.<br />;
   $six--;
}
```

Comment: Read http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php to understand how the loop works. You'll get used to it once you've done it enough times.

Comment: maybe you might benefit from explaining why you are confused. The code reads pretty clearly when you think about it. Loop beginning at 6 and count down. If $i is greater than 1 keep going. in your case, when $i hits 1 it no longer meets the requirement of being greater than one, as you wrote, so it does not print. Straight forward.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a question - you seem to know the syntax, and why it's failing, but you're just saying it confuses you?

Comment: Ok perhaps i should remember that `The first expression (expr1) is evaluated (executed) once unconditionally at the beginning of the loop. In the beginning of each iteration, expr2 is evaluated. If it evaluates to TRUE, the loop continues and the nested statement(s) are executed. If it evaluates to FALSE, the execution of the loop ends.

At the end of each iteration, expr3 is evaluated (executed). `

Comment: Ok `ernie` its confusing because i dont like to think backwards i like to run loop not while condition is true but rather before condition is meet in expr2

Comment: If that's the case, use a while loop, with the condition while `$i!=1`.  In any case, PHP isn't going to change for you, and this is a pretty standard convention among most programming languages.

Comment: It's not necessarily thinking backwards either. Believe all of us, this is one of the most common things you will do in programming. Very elementary stuff. You'll get used to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This confusion may not be only for `for()` statement but for other types of loop. You can use `$six >= 1` or `$six > 0`

Example 1

```
$six = 6;
do {
    echo $six . "<br>";
    $six --;
} while ( $six >= 1 );
```

Example 2

```
$six = 6;
for($i = $six; $i >= 1; $i --) {
    echo $i . "<br>";
}
```

Example 3

```
$six = 6;
while ( $six >= 1 ) {
    echo $six . "<br>";
    $six --;
}
```

Lastly you might decide not to even use any default PHP loop

```
$six = 6;
__loop($six);

function __loop($x) {
    echo $x . "<br>";
    $x --;
    ($x < 1) ? $x : __loop($x);
}
```

They would all return the same thing

```
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply change your "base case" to `$i > 0`

Alternatively, change the operator to `$i >= 1`

Comment: If i work not with array or array that starts with 1 (not 0) and use `$i > 0` then if i have to use `$i` inside loop i going to have to do `$i+1` each time which confusing even more.

Comment: No, no. :) You can do it with this without making it confusing. Just remember that array index values ALWAYS start at 0, not 1. Therefore, you will need to loop ONE extra time in your for() loop somehow, whether that is setting the base case to 0 instead of 1, or adding `$i+1` as you have suggested. This is a VERY common beginner error called "off by one" error. But don't feel bad, because even the most advanced programmers in the world still make this mistake, because it is not natural for the human being to start counting from 0 instead of 1. :)

Comment: There are exceptions to every rule. If you naturally count from zero, you probably also speak in broad generalities to other human beings. ;)

Answer (score 0):

To explain more clearly, you're saying to perform the code in the loop if `$i > 1`

So if $i *is* 1 then it will not perform the code. 1 is not greater than 1.

As lojik said use `$i > 0`  or `$i >= 1`

Comment: I guess >= is the better way than changing the number +1 or -1.

Comment: I think the better way is what makes the most sense to you. But I agree and would prefer to use >= myself in this case.

Answer (score 0):

In English, the for loop syntax is doing this:

```
At the start of the loop, $i is equal to $six.
Run the loop 'while' $i is greater than 1.
At the end of each running on the looping statement, decrement 1 from $i.
```

So, when $i is decremented to the value of 1, the conditional statement `$i > 1` no longer returns true, because it is checking that $i is greater than 1.

Like lojik said, use $i > 0 or $i >= 1, therefore when $i is equal to 1, the condition passes, and stops because on the next loop, $i is less than the compared value (in your example 1).  After the for loop, if you checked the value of $i, you will see it equals 0, which fails the condition.